# JAWS is not reading the drop down field as required even if the field is required

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have two fields in my page 
1. Name field: This is text field and is required. JAWS correctly read it as "Name field required" something like this.

2. Usage: This is a drop down field which is also required. JAWS correctly says it is a drop down field but never read it as required.

here is the HTML code

```
<tr widget="usage">
    <td>
        <span id='usage_required' class='required'>*</span><label for='ydlr8fo' widgetLabel='usage'>Usage:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="usage" id="ydlr8fo" class="" widgetField="usage" required aria-invalid="false" title="Usage">
            <!-- options omitted -->
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

use aria-required="true"
JAWS respects the aria-required attribute for SELECT elements in Chrome, FF, and IE.

[See WAI-ARIA spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-required](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-required)